# How do I fix this Command "npm run build" exited with 1 problem when deploying to vercel?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, vercel, wagmi

My code is working perfectly on my local host but when i try to deploy it to vercel, I get the error message below while trying to deploy the site;

✓ 1403 modules transformed.

✓ built in 4.88s

"EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-provider/dist/esm/provider.js".

file: /vercel/path0/onchain-roullete/node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-provider/dist/esm/provider.js:1:9

1: import { EventEmitter } from "events";
^
2: import { IJsonRpcProvider, isJsonRpcResponse, formatJsonRpcRequest, isJsonRpcError, getBigIntRpcId, } from "@walletco...

3: export class JsonRpcProvider extends IJsonRpcProvider {
error during build:
RollupError: "EventEmitter" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external", imported by "node_modules/@walletconnect/jsonrpc-provider/dist/esm/provider.js".
at error (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
at Module.error (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-
roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:13604:16)
at Module.traceVariable (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-

roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:14029:29)
at ModuleScope.findVariable (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:12547:39)

```
at ChildScope.findVariable (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:7082:38)

at ClassBodyScope.findVariable (file:///vercel/path0/onchain-roullete/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:7082:38)
```

[I made a screenshot of the error i got and you can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfEEt.png)

Comment: As far as I know the deployment is handled by vercel, you only have to push your code and let vercels' CI/CD do the deployment.

Comment: You may want to try the [solution here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/15415)  . See comment by FernandoChu

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this polyfills plugin library for Vite:
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node-polyfills**

Install it and then add it to your Vite config file.